# Elegant way of adding an CTA to a menu in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, menu

I'm new to WP and looking to put a CTA to my main menu. Currently the *ordinary* items are left aligned, and the CTA would be right aligned. So far this is what I've thought:

- Hardcode it into the theme with the link to the page. Easy but ugly and error prone + the editor/author can't edit the link.
- Define a secondary menu and just get first item (`wp_get_nav_menu_items`?). Better but seems odd to use a menu just to get an element.

Any other idea? Is there the WP way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this item as last in your menu, then assign custom class to this item and add required styles (positioning, CTA styles).

Comment: I've moved the question to [WordPress Stackexchange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/221855/elegant-way-of-adding-an-cta-to-a-menu). Even if I don't like the answer I accept it since it's valid and it's the only one. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I guess this is the easiest way. As far it will also allow to change the CTA text in a matter of few clicks